# Using NSIS, how to let user choose option on uninstall?

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

I'm using NSIS and the Modern User Interface 2.  During uninstall, I want to let the user select whether to delete saved application data or not by clicking a checkbox... What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I have to do this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have two options:

- Put the optional code in a separate uninstall section and add a component page in the uninstaller
- Create a custom page with a checkbox and store the users choice in a variable and check this variable in your delete code

Comment: So you can add a component section to the uninstaller in exactly the same manner as one would to the installer?

Comment: @Cuga yes (There is no such thing as a component section, all sections with a name are visible on the component page (if you have one))